# Expression Blend 4 Doesn't Work in Windows 8

Tags: wpf, windows-8, expression-blend-4

When I run Expression Blend 4 on my Windows 8 x64, it just shows the splash screen and closes itself. Is there any way to make it work on W8?

I have tried re-installing Expression Blend 4, uninstalling Expression Blend 5 but the same problem arises.

Comment: Have you checked the eventlogs for errors? Out of curiosity why would you install Blend 4 on W8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran it with `Run this program in compatibility mode for: Windows XP (SP3)` and `Run this program as an administrator` option. Opened up a bit slow but worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running it in compatibility mode for the time being?

Comment: Wow really? Have to say that's surprising, do you get any kind of an error you could post for reference?

Comment: Have you tried any of these? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/toolsforwinapps/thread/38847ac8-e387-4af6-8411-c9c95c27e67f

Answer (score 0):

Try the following fix:

**Create a bat file with this information (Expression Blend 4 Fix.bat):**

```
cd  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\Microsoft.Expression.Framework.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\Microsoft.Expression.Project.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend 4\Microsoft.Expression.WindowsPhone.dll"
```

**Create a bat file with this information (Expression Blend 5 Fix.bat):**

```
cd  %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend Preview for Silverlight 5\Microsoft.Expression.Framework.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend Preview for Silverlight 5\Microsoft.Expression.Blend.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend Preview for Silverlight 5\Microsoft.Expression.Project.dll"
ngen uninstall "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Expression\Blend Preview for Silverlight 5\Microsoft.Expression.WindowsPhone.dll"
```

Run the bat file as a Administrator

Or Download it from my [SkyDrive](https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=7685C6B143C95262&resid=7685C6B143C95262!209&authkey=AGmcdVMHGiVAgQo)